# how to highlight a option which is in view bag

Tags: html, listview, razor, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

```
In Mvc Controller:
Viewbag.c1="female";

In Mvc view:

@Html.DropDownList("c1",new List<SelectListItem>
  {
  new SelectListItem{ Text="male", Value="male"},
  new SelectListItem{ Text="female", Value="female"}
  }                                
)
```

how i can select the dropdownlist option "female" using that ViewBag.

Comment: What you want? You want to set `female` selected when page loads.

Comment: yes..gender value is stored in database, which is fetched on_load and that value must be selected.